# Reading complex xml in C#

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

i am trying to read an xml file, the format of the file as follow:

```
<rootnode>
<a>first<b>1st</b></a>
<a>second<b>2nd</b></a>
</rootnode>
```

i tried to use XDocument like this:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("a")
                   select new myClass
                   {
                       Word = (string)query.Value,
                       secondWord = (string) query.Element("b")
                   };
```

but it didnt work, as the (string)query.Value will bring me the whole line;"first**1st**"

is there any way to get the text instead of the whole element?

Comment: If you have any contorl over the xml, I would seriously suggest refactoring it to something more maintainable, eg. `<item><a>first</a><b>1st</b></item>`.  If you can do that, your code becomes cleaner, and less likely to break in the event of needing to add a `<c>` element later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really in a position to do much exploration of the "correct" way to handle this in the XML, but how about if you did some string manipulation on the result?

```
 var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("a")
     select new myClass
     {
         Word = (string)query.Value.Substring(0, ((string)query.Value).Length - ((string)query.Element("b").Value).Length),
         secondWord = (string)query.Element("b")
     };
```

Ugly, but it works.  I'm sure there's a "better" way, but as I say, I don't have enough bandwidth to look into it at the moment.

**EDIT**

As I mentioned in a comment to the original question, if you are in control of writing the XML in the first place, it would be better to reformat it - possibly like this.

```
<rootnode>
  <item><a>first</a><b>1st</b></item>
  <item><a>second</a><b>2nd</b></item>
</rootnode>
```

Not only does this enable you to tidy up the code to get clean values, but allows flexibility to add more data items inside each element if needs be.  e.g.

```
<rootnode>
  <item><a>first</a><b>1st</b><c>primary</c></item>
  <item><a>second</a><b>2nd</b><c>secondary</c></item>
</rootnode>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Descendants to be from "rootnode" rather than "a". Try this:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var data = (from query in loadedData.Descendants("rootnode")
    select new myClass
    {
        Word  = (string)query.Element("a"),
        secondWord  = ((string)query.Element("b"))
    });
```